Animal Reincarnation Mystery Movie
A black and white movie (40s, maybe, as I remember the costumes). A dog is poisoned and goes to heaven. He is sent back to Earth as a private detective named Rex. He is given a female companion who was a horse in her previous life. They are supposed to solve the mystery of who killed the dog and why. I have no idea what this movie is called.

The B&W comedy You Never Can Tell from 1951.

A cracker tycoon leaves six million dollars to his German Shepherd King, with his secretary Ellen as trustee. King is poisoned; Ellen inherits and is the prime suspect. But King's spirit, in 'Beastatory,' thinks he knows who did it and wants the chance to prove it. Enter Rex Shepherd, [King reincarnated as a] private eye, who snacks on dog food, and his sweet-talking secretary Goldie, a former race horse. But is Rex barking up the wrong tree?

Here's a clip:



